# How to use redis as message queue in asp.net core 1.0?

Tags: asp.net, redis, asp.net-core-1.0

How to use Redis as message queue in asp.net core 1.0?
How to connecting Redis in asp.net core 1.0?

Answer (score 0):

The package `Microsoft.Extensions.Caching.Redis` allows you to work with Redis cache, but this package currently does NOT support running on .NET Core. This is because this package relies on `StackExchange.Redis.StrongName` package which does not have a release version of package supporting .NET Core.

Comment: How is this an answer to the question? The OP asked for a message queue for .NET Core, but the proposed `Microsoft.Extensions.Caching.Redis` doesn't implement a message queue, and at the time of the answer it didn't support .NET Core